# CSS aspect ratio property bugged on iOS 14.7.1

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am building an app which uses `aspect ratio` CSS property to control the `width` of an element with only setting its `height`. Unfortunately `aspect ratio` doesn't seem to work on my `Iphone 11` which runs `iOS 14.7.1`.

This MWE:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background: darkgray;
    }
    div {
      height: 20vh;
      aspect-ratio: 1;
      background: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

produces different results on my `development machine` (left) and the `Iphone 11` (right):

[image]
[image]

The `width` of `div` on the `Iphone` runs wild because `aspect ratio` is not working. This is the case with `chrome` as well as `safari`. Any workaround?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct - https://caniuse.com/?search=aspect-ratio says aspect ratio not supported on Safari IOS14... Is the 20vh of the height known or is it just for the demo. If it's known then set width: 20vh at the same time.

Comment: Does this mean that it only sbouldn't work in `Safari`? Because it also doesn't in `Chrome`.

Comment: As I understand it on IOS any browser has basically the same underlying engine as Safari (and hence the same bugs).

Comment: Safari is the new Internet Explorer. Don't expect new and cool feature to work there.

Comment: @AHaworth Well, the the `height` of my element was in `percent` of its `parent`. I have to find another solution now.

Comment: Already works with iOS 15

Answer (score 0):

As Safari at least on IOS 14 and less at the time of writing this does not implement aspect-ratio we have to find another way.

One way is to size the div by putting an image in it which is square, setting the div's height to whatever % is required and with width auto by default if the image is given height 100% and with width defaulting to auto it fills the required space and we get a square of the right size.

This is not pretty because it requires an addition to the HTML in order to get the styling right but it does seem to work. The square image can be an inline SVG so no extra file required.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background: darkgray;
    }
    
    div {
      height: 20%;
      background: blue;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    img {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1' height='1'><rect fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%'/></svg>" />
  </div>
</body>
```